# The relationship between generic-lens and DataKinds GHC extension

Tags: haskell

If I try to access a field of a type using the @ symbol in generic-lens package GHC complains about enabling the DataKinds extension. Can you explain me in simple English what's the relationship generic-lens and DataKinds?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`DataKinds` is an extension that allows data types to be promoted to the type-level. What this means precisely is kind of a can of worms (it's one step on the way to dependent types), so I'll try and keep this explanation focused on just why generic-lens uses it (but bear in mind I'm simplifying here).

First, a quick detour. What's the type of the following expression?

```hs
mempty
```

`mempty` comes from the `Monoid` class. However, in contrast to most methods, it doesn't take any arguments. So how does Haskell know which type to instantiate it as? All of the following are true:

```hs
mempty == []
mempty == Sum 0
mempty == Any False
```

In short, Haskell (or GHC, rather) *infers* the type of the expression, and uses that inference to pick the right implementation. Sometimes, inference doesn't work. In the following expression, for instance:

```hs
print mempty
```

We would have to give the type explicitly, like so:

```hs
print (mempty :: [Int])
```

The `@` symbol is a syntax for applying any type that would usually be inferred. So, in this case, we could have written:

```hs
print (mempty @[Int])
```

It's not the same as `::`, though: the `@` symbol specifically fills the first type hole that ghc was trying to guess. So we could have equally applied it in front of print:

```hs
print @[Int] mempty
```

So, you can see that `@` is a way for us to apply a type to an expression. What it really lets us do, though, is get a *value* from a *type* (easily). For instance:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

class TypeName a where
    name :: String

instance TypeName Int where
    name = "Hello, I'm an Int!"

instance TypeName Bool where
    name = "Bool!"

name @Int
```

In other words, we can have type-level programs produce value-level results. And this is where generic-lens comes in. This package uses it for fields. When you have a type like the following:

```hs
data Person
  = Person
  { name :: String
  , age  :: Int 
  }
```

You could produce two lenses, one called `_name`, and the other `_age` (or something). What generic-lens does is slightly more clever: it has one function ([`fieldLens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-lens-1.1.0.0/docs/Data-Generics-Labels.html#v:fieldLens)) which you use like this:

```hs
-- age lens
fieldLens @"age"
```

Here, finally, is where we need `DataKinds`. Traditionally speaking, only types are allowed at the type level, which is what the `@` symbol deals with. That above is a string, though: lifting this restriction is precisely what `DataKinds` does.

Finally, you don't technically *need* `DataKinds` to fake the above behavior. You could just use types again. In fact, before `DataKinds`, people used to do things like the following:

```hs
data AgeField = DontConstructMe

fieldLens @AgeField
```